# JBoss 5 - CA signed certificate causes java.io.IOException: excess private key

Tags: ssl, jboss, key, private

I have a JBoss 5.0.1.GA instance. We have been using a self-signed SSL certificate on this JBoss server for a long time with no problem.

Finally we received a CA signed certificate and I went ahead and dropped it in.

Now I get this error (below). Can you please help me figure out what is going on?

```
2012-06-06 13:19:12,998 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (main) Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-192.168.2.8-8080
2012-06-06 13:19:12,999 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] (main) Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-192.168.2.8-8009
2012-06-06 13:19:13,099 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (main) Error initializing endpoint
java.io.IOException: excess private key
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:456)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:139)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1029)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.init(StandardService.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:510)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:575)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatService.startService(TomcatService.java:312)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:376)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.pojoStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:221)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor226.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
    at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1500)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:943)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
    at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1500)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:943)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
    at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1500)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:943)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:121)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:51)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:698)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:304)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:205)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:405)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the self-signed key still in your keystore - so the server doesn't know which one to choose: The self-signed or the CA-issued.

Remove the self signed (excess) one.

Comment: We are using ikeyman. I opened the jks file with it. Deleted the self-signed cert and imported the CA cert (pfx file). I may have screwed this up. I am going to try to re-create the entire JKS file.

Comment: Hi Olaf - we removed the entire keystore and re-created it. we still get this error. Is there anything I can do to figure out who the excess key is? Is it coming from the truststore?

Comment: Hm... Could you make extra extra *extra* sure that you have a new keystore? i.e. remove *all* matching keys and see if you get an error about a missing key? I'm not familiar with JBoss https setup and where it looks for the keys, but I've seen multiple (surprising) keystores in use more than once. Many times people (including me) have been convinced that they changed the right (and only) keystore when in fact there was another. You can use keytool to look what's in the keystore *if* you look into the correct keystore.

Comment: Your advice: remove all matching keys and see if you get an error about a missing key - is good advice. That can prove if we are really removing the existing key or not.

Comment: Yep - repeated the process and it worked. I followed a more manual command based process instead of using ikeyman and it worked.